# Difference between 2 images with transparency

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have the following 2 images

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

And I am trying to achieve the following outcome (the image has transparency).

[image: difference]

My current solution is to 'brute force' the difference, but it's really inefficient. (`prev` and `curr` are `Image` objects).

```
def compare(prev, curr):
    out = PIL.Image.new("RGBA", curr.size)
    width, height = curr.size
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if prev.getpixel((x, y)) == curr.getpixel((x, y)):
                out.putpixel((x, y), (0, 0, 0, 0))
            else:
                out.putpixel((x, y), (*curr.getpixel((x,y)),))
    return out
```

I have access to PIL and numpy. Is there a better way using these 2 libraries?

Comment: Seems like an O(n) solution to me (where n is the number of pixels in the image).

Comment: This looks like it would do the trick. https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/10/11/how-to-create-a-diff-of-an-image-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curr* np.any(prev!=curr, axis=2, keep_dims=True)`

If `curr` and `prev` are numpy arrays and you want to replace with 0 at indices where `curr==prev`, then you could do `np.any(prev!=curr, axis=2)` to get a binary mask which will be 1 where `prev` and `curr` are not equal and zero elsewhere. and then you can multiply it with curr.

Comment: This will not work. You'd have to add `keepdims=True`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks for pointing that out. Updated, thanks very much